# Error while installing window phone sdk 8.0

Tags: windows, sdk

It show 1 error .

A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. I changed the system date to 5 months back and successfully installed the software.

Answer (score 0):

To work around this problem, follow these steps:
Uninstall the partial installation of Windows Phone SDK 8.0. 
Take one of the following actions:
If you are trying to install the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 by using the installation DVD, you should run the Win8SharedSDKTools.msi file from the following folder on the DVD:

Root_of_DVD\Packages\Windows_SDK
If you are trying to install the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 by using the web download, you should download the following four files from the Microsoft Download Center, save the files to a download folder, and then run the Win8SharedSDKTools.msi file from the download folder.

The following files are available for download from the Microsoft Download Center:

DownloadDownload the Win8SharedSDKTools.msi package now.

DownloadDownload the Windows_SDK/69661e20556b3ca9456b946c2c881ddd.cab package now.

DownloadDownload the Windows_SDK/e072b3b3d3164e26b63338dce51862a7.cab package now.

DownloadDownload the Windows_SDK/e3d1b35aecfccda1b4af6fe5988ac4be.cab package now.